# Django REST drf-spectacular wrong detection of nested fields

Tags: django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

if there are more than one fields with relations to other models and depth>=1 is specified on the serializer Meta class, in the example generated for the corresponding url, all of the relation fields have the same object as their value, for example:

model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class OrderType(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    type = models.ForeignKey('OrderType', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

serializer:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

the example in echema:

```
{
  "user": {
      "number": 0
  },
  "type": {
      "number": 0
  }
}
```

there are also this warning:

```
NestedSerializer: Encountered 2 components with identical names "Nested" and different classes <class 'rest_framework.serializers.ModelSerializer.build_nested_field.<locals>.NestedSerializer'> and <class 'rest_framework.serializers.ModelSerializer.build_nested_field.<locals>.NestedSerializer'>. This will very likely result in an incorrect schema. Try renaming one.
```

but if depth is not used and the related fields are assigned with their serializers the schema is correct:

serializer:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    type = OrderTypeSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
```

the example in schema:

```
{
  "user": {
    "username": "string",
    "title": "string"
  },
  "type": {
    "number": 0
  }
}
```

how can the correct example be generated when nesting is done by using depth?

```
djangorestframework==3.12.3 
drf-spectacular==0.20.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from the DRF documentation:

> The depth option should be set to an integer value that indicates the depth of relationships that should be traversed before reverting to a flat representation.
> If you want to customize the way the serialization is done you'll need to define the field yourself.

The problem is that *drf-spectacular* has a hard time knowing how the nested fields should be represented beforehand, since there is no "explicit" serializer.

I believe when `depth` is used, DRF simply passes nested data through a on-the-fly `ModelSerializer` and then does `json.dump`.

Your second `OrderSerializer` is the preferred way. It gives you more guarantees for you data exposure, and as an added benefit is parse-able by spectacular.

TL;DR: `depth` is not supported at the moment. If you think this should be supported, open a github issue.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I switched back to drf-yasg because it supports depth. the problem with explicitly using a serializer for a nested field is that you either have to put all related serializers in one file, or potentially there will be the problem of circular imports.

Comment: this fixes circular serializer issues: https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular/blob/812d3ffd39347241ea9ac38793d6801cc6b17136/drf_spectacular/helpers.py

Comment: seems like good idea, thanks!